# GraphQL Mutation Error: "Field `parts` is not defined by type 'ProjectInput'"

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am working on a GraphQL mutation to create a project with associated `phones` and their `parts`, in other words relationship between is so: Phone can have multiple `parts`. I have defined a schema for querying phones along with their parts. However, I am encountering an error when trying to create a project with this data structure.

I have the following GraphQL mutation:

```
mutation createProject(
  $title: String
  $phones: [ID]
  $parts: [ID]
) {
  createProject(
    data: {
      title: $title
      phones: $phones
      parts: $parts
    }
  ) {
    data {
      id
      attributes {
        title
        phones {
          data {
            id
            attributes {
              name
              parts {
                data {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here are my query variables:

```
   {
  "title": "test",
  "phones": 28,
  "parts": [2, 6] 
}
```

The error message I'm getting is: "Field 'parts' is not defined by type 'ProjectInput'." I have checked my schema, and it appears to be correctly defined.

Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? Thank you!

```
type ProjectInput {
title: String
phones: [ID]
}
```

**Note**

If i remove **parts** from mutation and run, the mutation will be successful. The problem happens, only when parts is added to the query

Comment: The `GetAllPhones` part of your schema is not relevant to the question - need the definition of `createProject`

Comment: @MichelFloyd read the comments below, please.

Comment: @MichelFloyd what do you mean by "the definition of createProject"?

Comment: In your server schema `createProject` will be defined as `mutation { createProject(data: ProjectInput!): someType` - you will also have something like `input type ProjectInput { title: String! phones: [Phone!]! parts: [Part!]! }` - please include these definitions in your question since they define the interface of your mutation.

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks for help, i found it and updated my post.
The problem is now that "parts" are not included in `ProjectInput / phones`. 
Then how query works fine?

Comment: @MichelFloyd 
The problem is now that "parts" are not included in `ProjectInput / phones`. 
It's because it's a defined in `phones`, but not in ProjectInut.

Comment: @MichelFloyd one more thing: as a  server I’m using strapi cms.

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks for getting me to the point that I was missing. 
Can you formulate your answer so that i mark it as a correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ProjectInput` input type definition doesn't allow for a `parts` key. You'll need to alter the `ProjectInput` input type *on the server* to allow for an array of `part` ids if you really need to pass these in your mutation.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
Unfortunately this didn't work. And error was the same.
Furthermore, if i remove `parts` from mutation and run, the mutation will be successful. 
The problem happens, only when parts is added to the query

Comment: one more thing to mention: mutation is successful both if in query variables  "phones" is an array or a number. {"phones": [28]} or {"phones": 28} both work fine when parts is excluded from the mutation.

Comment: One more thing worth to mention: Error appears on this line: " parts: $parts". 
Does it mean that parts should be included somehow inside the phones object?

Smth like this? "phones: {phones: $phones,  {parts: $parts} }"?

Comment: That's why we need to know what a `ProjectInput` looks like.